# Point Cloud Library - CloudViewer showCloud() - Passing constant pointer - Visualizing STL file

Tags: c++, pointers, point-cloud-library

## Background

---

I'm sorry to bother you with such a trivial question. But I can't seem to get it right. It's been a while since I used any C++ so I'm probably doing something very basic, very wrong.

What I'm trying to accomplish is load a `.stl` mesh file to PCL's `cloudViewer`. I however can't seem to get a good variable that I can pass to `showCloud()`.

`showCloud()` is defined as follows:

```
void pcl::visualization::CloudViewer::showCloud(const ColorCloud::ConstPtr & cloud, const std::string & cloudname = "cloud")
```

Which leads me to believe I need to pass a constant pointer to the method. A regular pointer (?) seems to work as well. It's the way the [PCL tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cloud_viewer.php) did it, and that did work. I however have a need to load a mesh and not a straightly created `PointCloud`. Here's how it's accomplished in the tutorial with a regular `PointCloud`:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("my_point_cloud.pcd", *cloud);

pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

//blocks until the cloud is actually rendered
viewer.showCloud(cloud);
```

## Code

---

I've converted it to something that almost works, but I can't seem to pass the right variable to the `showCloud()` method.

```
pcl::PolygonMesh mesh;
pcl::io::loadPolygonFile("path/to/mesh.stl", mesh);

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud;
pcl::fromROSMsg(mesh.cloud, cloud);

pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

//blocks until the cloud is actually rendered
viewer.showCloud(cloud);
```

## Errors

---

The error message my IDE (VS2010) gives me is:

```
Error: no instance of overloaded function "pcl::visualization::CloudViewer::showCloud" matches argument list
```

## What have I tried

---

I've tried converting the `cloud` variable to a pointer, constant pointer, assigning it to a new pointer etc. but I just can't wrap my head around it. **When I change it to a pointer the `pcl::fromROSMsg()` method complains about a same error.** So when one method works, the other doesn't. Here's a couple of things I've tried (they might not all make sense):

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_ptr;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud;
pcl::fromROSMsg(mesh.cloud, cloud);
//...
cloud_ptr = cloud*;
//...
viewer.showCloud(cloud_ptr);

//or...
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud;
pcl::fromROSMsg(mesh.cloud, cloud);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_ptr (cloud);

//or...
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloud_const_pointer = &cloud;
pcl::fromROSMsg(mesh.cloud, cloud);
//...
viewer.showCloud(cloud_const_pointer);

//or...
viewer.showCloud(&cloud);
//etc. etc.
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a different way to visualize my `.stl` file with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17491042/1294864):

```
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>

int 
main ()
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>());
    pcl::PolygonMesh triangles;
    pcl::io::loadPolygonFileSTL("C:/Users/bono/Documents/Kinect2/Meshes/MeshedReconstructionAnderson.stl", triangles);
    pcl::fromROSMsg(triangles.cloud, *cloud);

    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");  
    //blocks until the cloud is actually rendered
    viewer.showCloud(cloud);

    //use the following functions to get access to the underlying more advanced/powerful
    //PCLVisualizer

    //This will only get called once
    viewer.runOnVisualizationThreadOnce (viewerOneOff);

    //This will get called once per visualization iteration
    viewer.runOnVisualizationThread (viewerPsycho);
    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
        //you can also do cool processing here
        //FIXME: Note that this is running in a separate thread from viewerPsycho
        //and you should guard against race conditions yourself...
        user_data++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```